# Typescript class decorators as Mixins

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm looking to improve on some code that I feel is a good representation of using class decorators as mixins with Typescript [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512151/typescript-class-decorators-add-class-method) question is exactly what I'm looking for but with a solution of 'Not Possible' I started hacking away.

the result is this working code

```
declare type Constructor<T = {}> = new(...args: any[]) => T

//Permissions function runs when @Permissions is placed as a class decorator
export function Permissions<TBase extends Constructor>(Base:TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        read: boolean = false;
        edit: boolean = false;
        admin: boolean = false;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this.read = false;
            this.edit = false;
            this.admin = false;
        }
        isRead(): boolean {
            return this.read;
        }
        isEdit(): boolean {
            return this.edit;
        }
        isAdmin(): boolean {
            return this.admin;
        }
        setRead(value: boolean): void {
            this.read = value;
        }
        setEdit(value: boolean): void {
            this.edit = value;
        }
        setAdmin(value: boolean): void {
            this.read = value
            this.edit = value
            this.admin = value
        }
    }
}
// Interface to provide TypeScript types to the object Object
export interface IPermissions {
        read: boolean;
        edit: boolean;
        admin: boolean;
        constructor(...args: any[]);
        isRead(): boolean;
        isEdit(): boolean;
        isAdmin(): boolean
        setRead(value: boolean): void
        setEdit(value: boolean): void
        setAdmin(value: boolean): void
}
//Extends the User Object with properties and methods for Permissions
interface User extends IPermissions {}

//Class Decorator
@Permissions
class User {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string, ...args: any[]) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// Example instantiation.
let user = new User("Nic")
user.setAdmin(true);
console.log(user.name + ": has these Permissions; Read: " + user.isRead() + " Edit: " + user.isEdit() + " Admin: " + user.isAdmin())
```

The question that I have has to do with the Interface. I would like to create the interface definition dynamically from the Permissions function. So that all I really need to do is modify the permissions function in order to get the proper types in the user object

is there a way to do that in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr
as of writing sadly i don't think so.

In my util lib I am having the same problem with a Poolable mixin that also implements IPoolable.

```
export function Poolable<T extends Constructor>(Base: T): T & ICtor<IPoolable> {
    return class extends Base implements IPoolable {
        public __pool__: Pool<this>;
        public release() {
            this.__pool__.release(this);
        }
        public initPool(pool: Pool<this>): void {
            this.__pool__ = pool;
        }
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
    };
}
```

And doing the mixin dance it works, passing interfaces along.

```
class Base {}
class Obj extends Poolable(Base) {}
let pool = new Pool(Obj);
```

But the following code does not.

```
@Poolable
class Base {}
const pool = new Pool(Base);
```

To me this is a bug and I hope they fix it soon.