# How do you access `this` in a method added to a class via a decorator in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I've just started using decorators in Typescript and I'm having trouble with adding a method to a class.

How would you access `this` in the added method. For example:

```
const decorator = (target: any): void => {
    target.prototype.doSomething = () => {
        // how can you access the class instance here?
        console.log('in the new method! value =', this.myValue);
    };
};

@decorator
class Something {
    public myValue = 42;
}


const obj = new Something();
obj.doSomething(); // displays in the new method! value = undefined
```

I understand that the decorator receives the class as an argument and that's what it's modifying, so it makes sense that the instance (which hasn't been created yet) is not available. But at the time the method is invoked, the instance does exist.

I've read quite a number of discussions of decorators online, and there are lots of examples of using `console.log` to illustrate how these methods work, but I haven't found any that actually refer to using `this` in the method.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), this is how a classDecorator should look like:

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        newProperty = "new property";
        hello = "override";
    }
}
```

In your case:

```
function decorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        doSomething = function() {
            console.log("Value: " + this.myValue);
        }
    }
}

@decorator
class Something {
    public myValue = 42;

    public doSomething(){}
}


const obj = new Something();
obj.doSomething();
```

The class definition will be replaced by whatever is returned from the decorator and this way the "this" keyword will have the correct value.

The empty doSomething function in the original class is just a placeholder, because typescript has some problems understanding that a class has been changed after a decorator and will give you an error at the last line. Look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25119) or [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512151/typescript-class-decorators-add-class-method) for more information and other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. I just found the solution as you posted your answer. Aside from all the missing type information in my original code (which I left out intentionally), the most important part was **not using a fat arrow function to define `doSomething` in the decorator**. I completely forgot about the different meaning of `this` in that context.